# SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 with TFS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs, reportbuilder

In the past, I've used Visual Studio to create and deploy reports, but also check them into TFS for version control.  Now we're moving away from VS and toward Report Builder and my concern is version history.

Is there any way for the Report <strike>Server</strike> Builder to integrate with TFS (check-in/out)?  If not, have there been any solutions devised to handle source control?

Thanks!

EDIT: We're thinking of moving away from VS to Report Builder because of ease of use - just report building for power users.  Let someone/something handle the check-ins to source control.

Comment: A little brainstorming gave rise to the idea of having the report developer (a power user) modify reports in a test environment then request that the report be deployed to the production environment, at which point a developer would check it into TFS and handle the production deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Data Tools (the SQL Server 2012 replacement for BIDS) you have wonderful integration with TFS. I am not sure about Report Builder.

Comment: I just added something extra to my question - we're trying to keep this dirt simple for the report designers and we're thinking (maybe incorrectly) that Visual Studio is too much for power users.

Comment: In my experience if you give the users data via stored procedures or views they can learn to use the SSRS gui to build very powerful reports. Report Builder 3.0 has become a very powerful, easy to use, tool which is something you should also consider.

Comment: I've played around in Report Builder 3.0 a little bit and it's super easy to create reports.  My only concern is versioning.

Comment: Maybe report building at an enterprise level requires power users to use visual studio... not sure about that.